# Unknown encoding (\x001, not ASCII) to float in Python

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I have this string in Python `'\x005\x003\x00.\x000\x005\x006\x00'` that represents the number `53.056`.

I am trying to convert that to a float (`float()`) but if I try to cast it to a float I get `ValueError: could not convert string to float:`.

I read that every character beginning with `\x` is an ASCII character but I also know that in ASCII 5 is `\x05` and not `\x005` and that `\x00` is the number 0 and not a null value like in this case.

I also tried to encode that in UTF-8 but with no result.

What encoding is that and and how do I convert that string to a float?

Comment: Try UTF-16BE instead of UTF-8. That `\x005` is actually two characters, `\x00` and `5`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that chars are separated by a null byte `\x00`.
A solution would be:

```
s = b'\x005\x003\x00.\x000\x005\x006\x00'
float(s.replace(b'\x00',b''))
```

Answer (score 0):

The string has some `\x00` null characters that are causing the ValueError when you attempt to cast it to float. If you get rid of those, you should be able to call `float()` on it.

```
s = '\x005\x003\x00.\x000\x005\x006\x00'

float(''.join([char for char in s if char in '0123456789.']))
# or
float(s.replace('\x00', ''))
```